# Google Calendar API PHP - Missing Summaries & Descriptions

Tags: php, api, calendar, summary

Been trying for some time to get event summaries and descriptions with the following code but no luck. I've even used Googles' API Explorer but can't seem to get the API call to return this information. Any idea what I might be missing? Also, let me know if there is anything I need to clarify about the situation. Thanks for any help in advance. All the best.

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client(); 
$client->setApplicationName("Application Name Hidden Here"); 
$client->setDeveloperKey("API_KEY_HIDDEN_HERE");

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client); 

$calendarId = 'media@meditationincolorado.org';
$optParams = array(
  'maxResults' => 3,
  'orderBy' => 'startTime',
  'singleEvents' => TRUE,
  'timeMin' => date('c')
);
$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);

if (count($results->getItems()) == 0) {
  print "No upcoming events found.<br/>";
} else {
  print "Upcoming events:<br/>";
  foreach ($results->getItems() as $event) {
    $summary = $event->getSummary();
    if (empty($start)) {
      $start = $event->start->date;
    }
    echo $summary . '<br/>';
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same issue. No summaries or descriptions on events. However, I only see this happening on shared calendars. My primary calendar does show summaries. Have you been able to fix this since you last posted it?